# Is it correct to say " I have gone through all the way from a to b."?

Tags: grammaticality

For example, I am so proud myself that I have gone through all the way from Japanese language school to uni graduation.

Does it sound odd to English native speakers?

Comment: It sounds odd to me.  The word "through" is not needed.

Comment: Not too bad.  Better:  "I am so proud *of* myself that I have gone all the way through from Japanese language school to uni graduation."  "Uni" isn't used much in AmE for "university."  Maybe it's clear to anyone who knows you that it's a long way from Japanese language school to a university, but I had to assume that from context.

Answer (score 2):

No, a native speaker wouldn't say that.

You go "through" a single thing:  "I got all the way through university!"

You go from (or "all the way from") one thing to another:  "I got all the way from Japanese language school to uni graduation!"

Note too that you would be proud "of" yourself, but maybe that missing word is just a typo.  And usually you are "proud of yourself" for _____ing something, e.g., getting through university, driving all the way across the state, losing five pounds, reading from the beginning of the newspaper to the very end.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The above answers make me confused. So should I say "I'm so proud of myself for getting all the way from Japanese language school to university graduation"?

Comment: @Lilboi, that sounds fine to me.